# unique index violation, attempting to insert object graph on new context

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Referencing the code below, I have a list of `Error` objects that has been instantiated for insertion.  Each error has been assigned an `ErrorType` object which has been retrieved from the database.  When I attempt to insert the list of errors on a new context I get an exception from the database of `unique index violation` on ErrorType.  This makes sense as the new context assumes that the ErrorType object is also new, not knowing that it already exists in the database.  I have attempted to solve this by using Attach on ErrorType, as well as doing a re-query of all ErrorTypes in the database, however that didn't seem to help.  I ran the SQL Profiler and still see that EF is issuing an insert statement on the ErrorType entity.

**Edit**:  I also added "Try 1.5" which in conjunction with "Try 1" actually does the job.  I still don't understand why I have to go back and change all error.ErrorType references to point to the locally created and attached ErrorType object.  I understand that the original ErrorType and the locally created one are different objects in memory, but they share the same PrimaryKey, so my assumption was that Entity Framework understands that they are one and the same.

It also seems that I am unable to Attach the original FileErrorType (as opposed to the local) because it then attempts to attach the entire graph, that's why I chose to create a local copy of the FileErrorType object that has the same primary key value.

```
void InsertErrors(IList<Error> errors)
{
    using(var context = ....)
    {
        //Try 1:
        //asuming there is only 1 error type (true in my example)
        //ErrorType et = new ErrorType();
        //ErrorTypeId is the primary key
        //et.ErrorTypeId = errors[0].ErrorType.ErrorTypeId;
        //context.ErrorTypes.Attach(et);

        //Try 1.5
        //If I also add the followin code to Try 1, everything works, but I'm not sure why
        //foreach(var e in errors)
        //{
        //    error.ErrorType = et; //reassign to the locally created ErrorType object that has been Attached
        //}

        //Try 2:
        //var errorTypes = context.ErrorTypes.ToList();

        foreach(var e in errors)
        {
            context.Errors.AddObject(e);        
        }       

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the Errors, they and the associated ErrorTypes are marked as added and are inserted into the database on the call to SaveChanges.

Call attach on all of the ErrorType instances once they are associated with the context. This will change the state of the ErrorTypes to Unmodified and prevent them from being inserted during SaveChanges.

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I was doing.  If you read the comment in my "Try 1" you'll see that I only have 1 ErrorType instance.  In other words if you prove all error.ErrorType, they all point to the same entity with the same id.  So calling Attach on the first one in the list is sufficient.  Unless I'm missing your point.

Comment: In method 1, you are creating a new, local ErrorType instance. I assume that the Error objects within the errors parameter already have a reference to ErrorType instances (even if they all point to the same one). You should not need to create the new, local instance but rather just call Attach on the existing one coming in with the error parameter.

Comment: I initially tried to do that, however Attach attempts to attach as unmodified the entire graph, meaning all of the errors as well as all of the error types.  This causes an exception to be thrown because Attach does not allow more than one reference to the same object in the graph.  The alternative from what I read is to call AddObject() and then manually set the state to unchanged on all the ErrorType objects.  I guess my overall question is why doesn't the EF context recognize the local copy of ErrorType as being the same thing as the ones already attached to the errors. The Id is the same.

Comment: The key is to first add the errors and then attach the errortypes. They will already have been dragged into the context along with the errors so attaching the errortypes is only required to set the state to unmodified. You should not need to manually create a local errortype and should therefore nor have any problems with it being a duplicate.

Comment: Yes what you described is the alternative way of doing it as I suggested in my previous comment.  To be honest I didn't go down that path because I have a generic repository that implements Attach, but doesn't expose other methods to change states of entities.  The code I posted above was just a sample to simplify my scenario and get the point across.  I guess the core question that I have is how EF tracks entities.  It seems like it's not just the entity type and its primary key, it's also the actually memory reference?

Comment: Records loaded from the database are compared with entities that are already in the context. Matches are handled according to the MergeOption enumeration. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx Attach and Add do not include this logic.